# Why use <xsd:sequence> for a single <xsd:element>?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

```
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="allowFieldTruncation" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

In the above example, I have only one element (called `allowFieldTruncation`) defined under the complex type, and I have no requirement for `minOccurs` or *maxOccurs*. Now my question is why should I include a sequence tag – can't the definition be like below?

```
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="allowFieldTruncation" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the XSD spec [says so](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#element-complexType):

```
<complexType
  abstract = boolean : false
  block = (#all | List of (extension | restriction))
  final = (#all | List of (extension | restriction))
  id = ID
  mixed = boolean : false
  name = NCName
  {any attributes with non-schema namespace . . .}>
  Content: (annotation?, 
            (simpleContent | complexContent 
            | ((group | all | choice | sequence)?, 
               ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?))))
</complexType>
```

Think of `xsd:sequence` as one of several model groups required if you wish to specify an `xsd:element` in a content model.  (You could use another besides `xsd:sequence`.)  The design might have allowed no model groups to be specified for "groups" of one element, however as far as exceptions and irregularities go, XSD's squiggly, blurry line had to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: So,you mean to say it is just a specification the we need to follow if we have to use an element under a complex type?

Comment: Not "just" a specification.  "The" specification.  The W3C XML Schema Recommendation is the spec that defines the syntax and semantics of XSD, so yes, you have to follow it in this case and in general if you wish to use or implement XSD.  There are many XSD books that would serve as adequate proxies if you prefer.